How to sum in Excel row values from the row that had a specific value in another column
If a row from another column has a word (like Sum), how to make the other column sum up all the numbers from below the last Sum and until the previous row?
I need a formula to put in O5, O8 and O13. If possible, O2 and below should just do it via a table formulas as N1:O is a table called Table1.
Eventually the formula should look like =if(exact(N1, "Sum"), ???, RANDBETWEEN(1, 1000)) - the RANDBETWEEN is just an example, that will be another formula to determine actual numbers.



 
N
O




1
Sum
Numbers


2

20


3

35


4

10


5
Sum
=? should be 65


6

230


7

70


8
Sum
=? should be 300


9

1


10

2


11

3


12

4


13
Sum
=? should be 10




Try this formula in O2 and below:
=IF(EXACT(N2, "Sum"), SUM(O$1:O1)-2*SUMIF(N$1:N1, "Sum", O$1:O1), RANDBETWEEN(1,100))
Here's demonstration in AI2:
=IF(EXACT(AH2,"Sum"),SUM(AI$1:AI1)-2*SUMIF(AH$1:AH1,"Sum",AI$1:AI1),RANDBETWEEN(1,100))  


Nice!!! Just please edit to match the question (also added spaces) - O2 would be =IF(EXACT(N2, "Sum"), SUM(O$1:O1)-2*SUMIF(N$1:N1, "Sum", O$1:O1), RANDBETWEEN(1,100)).

I've accepted the answer anyway, but submitted an edit request per the above, hope it'll be accepted too.

I accepted these proposals for edition, as requested, but it seems to me that they do not bring much, apart from changing addresses, which is only an example anyway.

Thanks. It just makes it easier for those that read the question to reproduce the answer (if they copy the text values from the question).

Try the following:
 =SUM(O$2:O4)-SUMIF(N$2:N4,"Sum",O$2:O4)*2

It essentially sums the entire column then removes previously calculated sums
Sample:

If you want the sums to be in column P as in the screenshot of your comment, use the following:
=IF(N2="Sum",SUM(O1:O$2)-SUMIF(N1:N$2,"Sum",P1:P$2),"")

example:


it gives unrelated numbers, see screenshot.

See edit to my answer.

Showing P in the screenshot was just for demonstration, unfortunately it still gives wrong sums.

Works for me, please make sure you are copy/pasting it correctly.

Yeah, but it's because you edited and added *2 just now, which made it a duplicate of this answer. The only difference is that you used O$2 and they used O$1, which doesn't matter as o$1 is a string anyway.
